# How we can define condition in on exit(true) and on exit(false) of actions part in select output

Tags: conditional-statements, anylogic

For example, we consider defining the problem that has three levels of severity(1, 2, 3) and 2 variables(j, k), so on exit(true) in actions part of the select output, we want to define
severity(1 OR 3) AND (j=3)
and on exit(false) we want to define
severity(1 OR 3 OR 2) AND (k=2)
but unfortunately, we have an error as (Syntax error on token "||", invalid AssignmentOperator) and  Syntax error on token "&&" and  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.
how we can solve this problem? and other words How we can write conditions in actions block[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lllvu.jpg).

For example, we consider defining the problem that has three levels of severity(1, 2, 3) and 2 variables(j, k), so on exit(true) in actions part of the select output, we want to define
severity(1 OR 3) AND (j=3)
and on exit(false) we want to define
severity(1 OR 3 OR 2) AND (k=2)
but unfortunately, we have an error as (Syntax error on token "||", invalid AssignmentOperator) and  Syntax error on token "&&" and  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.
how we can solve this problem? and other words How we can write conditions in actions block.